# How to compile APK from command line?

Tags: android, windows, delphi, compilation, automation

I am interested in making Android apps on demand. Depending on the clients request, my web site would send me a JSON file direct to a Windows application that I have created in Delphi. This one would save the file inside the Android app source folder and then, execute a command line telling the Android compiler to generate the APK file and send it to my client, all that without my presence.

The Android project was made with [MotoDev](http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html). And it uses the Android SDK that is in my root.

How should I configure the command line to achieve this from inside my Delphi program?

I will also need to change the manifest to put a new version number so it does not conflict with other clients version.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Android uses the Ant build system, so you can create a `build.xml` and `build.properties` file for your project.

You'll need to create the `build.xml` file first though:

```
android update project -p .
```

This will generate a `build.xml` file. You should probably customize the build steps and targets for your project. A good idea in your case would be to have the `build.properties` file generated by your website for the specific build... Then include it via the `build.xml` file. In particular, you will need to specify in the `build.properties` file where the signing keys are, and what the password is:

**Build.Properties:**

```
key.store=keystore.dat
key.alias=signing_key
key.store.password=password123
key.alias.password=password123
```

The build process using `ant` also allows you to do variable replacements in Java files, which might be another idea. It would allow you to customize the build process further on a client by client basis.

By default, the build is triggered by:

```
ant clean
ant release
```

Another neat idea: Have Ant copy the resulting APK file to a network share accessible by the website by placing a `< copy ... />` line in the `< target name="release" >` section.

Comment: So, this build.properties is also a xml file? Would you show me a full example of those two files?

Comment: How to do the same in PHP Server ? @Andrew

Comment: I don't see any build.xml file in my existing project directory... You say `You'll need to create the build.xml file` but why wouldn't this already be created if I have already compile through, say... Eclipse/ADT?

Comment: What's this `android` command you're using? (Asking as a GNU/Linux user in a Windows-tagged question, but I assume the tools is cross-platform.)

Comment: Update from previous comment: The other answer (by Ciro) mentioned that it's supposed to be in `android-sdk/tools`.

Answer (score 5):

**Create build.xml at project creation time**

If you start a new project with:

```
android create project \
    --target 1 \
    --name MyName \
    --path . \
    --activity MyActivity \
    --package com.yourdomain.yourproject
```

the `build.xml` file used by `ant` will be generated.

The `android` tool is present in the `tools/` directory of the SDK which you downloaded.

**Create debug releases**

Besides:

```
ant release
```

for final releases, you can also create debug releases with:

```
ant debug
```

**Location of generated apk**

Generated apk are placed under `bin/`.

The most important outputs are:

```
MyName-debug.apk
MyName-release.apk
```

but some intermediate apks are also generated, in particular unaligned and unsigned versions.

But most of the time you can forget where they were created and just run:

```
ant debug install
ant release install
```

to get them installed. But make sure it is working with adb first: [adb devices command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510284/adb-devices-command-not-working)

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10, Android 23.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't directly use ANT build systems now. It uses Gradle, which is based on Groovy. You can learn more about build systems [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software).

You can see the list of available tasks you can run on using this command

```
gradlew tasks
```

To initiate a debug build, invoke the assembleDebug task

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

You can install your app using the adb tool via this command

```
adb install path/to/your_app.apk
```

To learn more about building on command line, follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline) comprehensive article.

Also you can read this article on "[Why Build Your Java Projects with Gradle Rather than Ant or Maven?](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/why-build-your-java-projects-with-gradle/240168608?pgno=1)"