# How to build .apk file on server side

Tags: php, android, android-build

My **simple version** of the question is ,how do i build .apk file on the server side ,assuming my server is  in PHP language.
 
`Long version` 
Step 1: I am taking data from HTML form
 
Step 2: I am generating the RSS feed for it using PHP classes
Step 3: I will modify the java file in the server side to update the URL of the RSS feed i have   generated in step 2
Step 4: Now i have all the files to build the Android app on the server side ,except that i have no info on how to build it actually .
ps: I have googled it ,I have not found any particular solution regarding Native Android apps ,Phone gap seems to have one solution ,but i am not interested in Phone gap.

Comment: im not sure what you mean ........ do you want an android app using php and html ??

Comment: You want the server to build an Android app automatically when some data changes? What's the point of that?

Comment: I want to build the android app on the server side ... the native app only .. but is there any php script to build it ..

Comment: You will find your answer and plenty of pointers here [How to compile APK from command line?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285331/how-to-compile-apk-from-command-line

Comment: no the URL changes automatically ,not the app ,and the app parses the data from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manage your Android project using the Ant and command line tools.
Lars Vogel's article is quite useful: [Creating Android applications via the command line and Apache Ant](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/03/16/creating-android-applications-via-the-command-line-ant/)

Official Android resources:

- [Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)
- [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Also have a look at this SO question [How to compile APK from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285331/how-to-compile-apk-from-command-line)

If all that changes in your application is the RSS URL, wouldn't you be better of by creating a RSS redirect feed on the server side and leave a static URL inside the Android application?

That way you will not need to keep recompiling and redeploying the app in the first place, just modify the RSS feed on the server side. You can maintain a session object and redirect different users to different locations, as you see fit.

[How to Properly Redirect Your RSS Feed](http://adage.com/article/power-150-blog/properly-redirect-rss-feed-301-redirects/135864/)

Comment: Yes i agree with you ,the command line is neat and the exact way of doing things ,how about doing on server side ? can i access command line on server side or is there any php script to simulate the same ? forgive my ignorance (i am a newbie in server)

Comment: @Vamsi you will need to install the command line tools on the server side and invoke them from your PHP application

Comment: @adrain Do you have any idea to install commandline tools in serverside. which type of command line tools need to install .
how the andriod development environment available to server.