# Make apk file on PHP

Tags: php, android, apk

I am developing a php project.I want to create online apk.How to create a apk file on php file?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manage your Android project using the Ant and command line tools. Lars Vogel's article is quite useful: [Creating Android applications via the command line and Apache Ant](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/03/16/creating-android-applications-via-the-command-line-ant/)

for more reference follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180386/how-to-build-apk-file-on-server-side) link

Comment: oh my god, what a brilliant answer