# eclipse android apk invalid

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, installation-package

Using eclipse to generate Android app.

All of a sudden when I export a project - I get an apk file that's not valid.
e.g. missing **`AndroidManifest.xml`** and **`res`** folder.

It was working a few days ago and I didn't make any `config` changes.

When I test it in an emulator - the correct apk file is generated in the **`bin`** folder -
albeit *without certificate signing* etc.

Answer (score 0):

A really hackish workaround is to go to Eclipse->Preferences->Android->Build and change the debug key to the cert you want to sign with. The downside is it's still built in debug mode. Eclipse can easily drive a good man insane trying to troubleshoot it. You might consider upgrading/reinstalling your version of Eclipse and/or reinstalling/upgrading to the latest ADT plugin.

If you don't have time to battle Eclipse, use the command line:

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

[How to compile APK from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285331/how-to-compile-apk-from-command-line)