# How to compile Android Project's with Windows command line using script?

Tags: android, bash, command-line, compilation, project

```
android create project --name YourProjectName --path C:\dev\YourProject --target android-3 --package com.company.testproject --activity MainActivity
```

i want to compile it with command line in windows.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your question is Duplicate, anyway this is for `Bash tag`, because you added in question !.

requirements for linux example (Debian base) :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

also :

```
android update sdk -u -t platform-tools
android update sdk -u -t name_of_android_target_platform
```

Target platforms are named like `android-7`, ***for Android API level 7***. If you need a non-android platform (for example: Google Inc.:Google APIs:7) then you need to find its numeric id.

Generate ./local.properties and ./build.xml based on your ./project.properties

```
android update project --path .
```

If you also need to generate ./project.properties (though normally you should have it in source control), you can do that with :

```
android update project --path . --target 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:7'
```

**Build debug apk :**

```
ant debug
```

**Build release APK:**

```
ant release
```

and this is for Creating keystore :

```
keystore=$projectname.keystore
alias=mykey
storepass=some_new_password
keypass=some_new_password2
keytool -genkey -v -keystore $projectname.keystore -storepass $storepass -keypass $keypass -validity 10000 -keyalg RSA
```

**Create signed release APK :**

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore $keystore -storepass $storepass -keypass $keypass bin/$projectname-release-unsigned.apk $alias
rm -f bin/$projectname-release.apk
zipalign -v 4 bin/$projectname-release-unsigned.apk bin/$projectname-release.apk
```

Usefull Resources :

[Building Android application (.apk) from the Command Line](http://www.raweng.com/blog/2012/11/02/building-android-application-apk-from-the-command-line-v2/)

[How to compile APK from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285331/how-to-compile-apk-from-command-line)

[Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) (from `developer.android.com`)

Cheers.!:)