# From Terminal or Java generate signed apk file from Android project

Tags: android, terminal, apk

I've checked out the android docs about creating an application from ant & then blatantly from terminal. I'm trying to figure out how eclipse is able to generate a signed apk file from an android project.... ?

A list of command would be helpful or if there is already a Java script out there I would probably propose on the spot.

Comment: Anything you can do from the Eclipse GUI, you can also do from a command line.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667741/how-to-generate-apk-file-using-a-command-line  `android update project -t android-10 -p .`

Answer (score 2):

Where did you check in the Android docs? A cursory google search produces this: [Building and Running from Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#DebugMode).

Comment: So here is the fix. make sure to have the correct pathing. @paulsm4 definitely had the right answer minus a few details e.g. android update project -t android-10 -p . where android is actually /path/to/android/sdk

Comment: then when you've done that & successfully built a build.xml file you can run ant release or ant debug